# Using iloc with list comprehension to set value

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm attempting to use list comprehension to iterate through a dataframe and set a new value to the location with iloc.  I have confirmed it is iterating through correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(10)]*10)

#working
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        df.iloc[i,j] = 0+i

#not working 
[df.iloc[i,j] = 5 for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]
```

Can someone explain why above won't work? or what will?

Comment: List comprehensions are for building lists. If you are not building lists then you shouldn't use list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do assignment statement `df.iloc[i,j] = 5` inside listcomp, so it doesn't work.  `df.iloc[i,j] = 5` doesn't return anything for listcomp to create a list and listcomp doesn't allow statements. You need assigment statement outside listcomp. Your listcomp may change to this

```
df[:] = [[5 for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

Out[17]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
1  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
2  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
3  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
6  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
7  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
8  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
9  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

However, I guess this is just an example you use to show the issue because there is better way to create such dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because a list comprehension requires a Python *expression* in its leftmost position.

```
[df.iloc[i,j] = 5 for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# This is a statement, not an expression.
```

This is a consequence of the Python language grammar, which is formally specified here:  [Python 3 Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)

You could rewrite this to use advanced indexing, I think.  Using different dimensions for rows and columns, for clarity:

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame([numpy.arange(4)]*7)
```

After which `df` is:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  2  3
1  0  1  2  3
2  0  1  2  3
3  0  1  2  3
4  0  1  2  3
5  0  1  2  3
6  0  1  2  3
```

You can assign with "fancy indexing", i.e. providing indices in a list:

```
df.iloc[[0, 2, 4], [2]] = 100
df.iloc[list(range(6)), list(range(2))] = 125
```

After which `df` is:

```
     0    1    2  3
0  125  125  100  3
1  125  125    2  3
2  125  125  100  3
3  125  125    2  3
4  125  125  100  3
5  125  125    2  3
6    0    1    2  3
```